# QGIS2Leaf help when trying to export

Tags: qgis, qgis2leaf, unboundlocalerror

So when I try to export to leaflet I get this Error and I dont know how to fix it....I went in to QGIS2LEAF export and imorted all my layers and selected OSM basemap and clicked Full screen, selected the ouput folder and when I went to click okay, it stalled and gave me this error.

```
An error has occured while executing Python code:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/RPM94/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2leaf\qgis2leafdialog.py", line 297, in export2leaf
    qgis2leaf_exec(self.outFileName, self.basemapName, self.basemapMeta, self.basemapAddress, self.width, self.height, self.extent, self.full_screen, self.layer_list, self.visible, self.opacity, self.encode2JSON,self.createcluster, self.webpage_name, self.webmap_head,self.webmap_subhead, self.legend,self.locate,self.address, self.precision, self.labels, self.labelshover, self.matchCRS, self.selected)
  File "C:/Users/RPM94/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2leaf\qgis2leaf_exec.py", line 290, in qgis2leaf_exec
    print '>> ' + crsProj4
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'crsProj4' referenced before assignment


Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]


QGIS version:
2.8.2-Wien Wien, 1b929ef

Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/RPM94/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/RPM94/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', u'C:/Users/RPM94/.qgis2//python', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISWI~1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools', 'D:/Presentation']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to unselect Layer Extent and go with Canvas Extent. This should fix the problem. Yet You can try to export with qgis2web. The fix for qgis2leaf might take a little longer due to missing capacities.

Answer (score 3):

qgis2leaf is no longer under active development:

https://github.com/Geolicious/qgis2leaf/issues/269

The issue is therefore perhaps unlikely to be fixed. Consider trying qgis2web as an alternative - it's a merge of qgis2leaf and qgis-ol3. It does not have all of qgis2leaf's functionality for Leaflet export, but it might achieve what you need.